# Confusion about output voltage

Tags: diodes

While solving these problems I'm confused about sign conventions of output voltages of IDEAL Diodes. Actually I can't get between which nodes the **V** is to be taken? Is it between +5 and -V? I solve them like this

a) V = +5 (Between +5 and 0) since diode is conducting.

but answer is **-5V**?  Can any one explain a bit?

[image]

Comment: Hint: Either the diode dominates, or the resistor dominates. They are wired to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: For (a), you should merely notice that the diode is arranged so that it conducts (is ***on***.) Assuming an ideal diode here, conduction means "zero voltage drop across the diode." If there isn't any voltage drop ***across*** the diode, then the voltage on both sides of the diode ***must*** be the same. That's how they came up with -5 V as the answer for (a).

Comment: @jonk I'm asking about where this -5 appears? Is it between Positive end of diode and -5?

Comment: @FanBoy It appears where the letter \$V\$ appears and it is relative to the same point that the two power supplies are also relative to.

Comment: All voltages are measured relative to "Zero volts", which isn't shown in those drawings, but is implied by the "+5V" and "-5V" labels.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer to a) is -5V, then your textbook is assuming an ideal diode with no forward drop.  An ideal diode is a perfect conductor when forward-biased, meaning there is no voltage drop across it. Therefore V must equal -5V.

Comment: Across which terminals the V is to be collected?

Comment: What makes you think these are ideal diodes?

Comment: Is this V between +ve terminal of diode and -5V?

Comment: @Sparky256 Book has mentioned it

Comment: @Sparky256 Because the correct answer, supposedly, is -5 V. Only way that happens is when the diode is "ideal."

Comment: @Sparky256: "What makes you think these are ideal diodes?" The textbook answer given is -5V. This is only possible with an ideal diode.

Comment: Ok, I give up. More irrational junk from the books or teachers. Why teach that which is not possible in real-world conditions?